# GNOME Disks Sample Size

Tags: disk, benchmark, gnome-disks

I'm trying to use GNOME Disks to test my disk performance and, according to my previous experience, I'd like to set the sample size to 8K, 16K and 32K. However, I see the minimal sample size in its interactive interface equal to 1MiB.

Is it any way (config file, command line options) to make this size less than 1MiB?

(I'm on Ubuntu VM with kernel 3.13.0-65)

**UPDATE:** My GNOME Disks version is 3.10.0, with UDisks 2.1.3.

It would be great to have any references to a more recent version of this tool, which could use more flexible settings for the sample size.

Comment: No, unless you're willing to look into the source code, you can't use a size less than 1MiB (this is with v. 3.22.1)